# Do IT job interviews in Australia require formal business attire?

Tags: interviewing, australia, dress-code

I'm an Indian IT professional looking to move to Australia. I've been accustomed to workplace casual attire throughout my career here, and even during job interviews it tends to be business casual, a full sleeved shirt over jeans is considered acceptable.

Is it similar in Australia, **in the IT sector specifically**, or do even IT companies and startups expect you to show up in a business suit?

Comment: `a full sleeved shirt over jeans is considered acceptable.` not always. I would not mind, but I know many who would.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think a suit is necessary for positions that aren't quite senior or managerial. I can offer some thoughts having worked near IT as a software developer.

As an Australian who has worked as a software engineer in three companies so far, personally I've always gone to job interviews with a collared shirt and nice pants, but no suit and tie. The same has been true for many other people I've seen applying.

Australia may be more laid back (a number of people I know here work every day in a tee-shirt and jeans), but in my experience I think it is not uncommonly expected that you try and dress to a higher standard than that for interviews. Historically in white-collar positions, I think people read it as a statement of your sincerity and values, but I'd also say this is rapidly changing.

I suppose the question is whether you're being interviewed by and meeting with people who are concerned with appearances and are 'old fashioned' like that, or with people who will prioritise your abilities and suitability for the role.

Personally, I'm not sure if I would be comfortable wearing jeans to one, as you never know who you'll meet at an interview (I've been introduced/presented to upper management before as part of a tour), so I think there's a judgement call to make based on what type of company it is. On the flipside, perhaps a company or manager that judged you on your dress isn't one you want to work for anyway?

Either way, the choice is yours, but I like to play it a little safe.

Comment: If in doubt, I don't think that going in slightly overdressed will do you much harm. You just might not feel that comfortable in a suit and tie on a hot day, although I'm sure the same applies in much of India.

Answer (score 3):

There is no general answer to this question because every company has its own culture and expectations.

The best thing you can do is email the interviewer, ask about dress code, and then dress one step better than that.

Comment: never hurts to ask. Here's the email a candidate sent me recently: subject: `Questions About First Day of Work
Mr. Hodges, 
I am looking forward to meeting you and the rest of the team on Friday. I have a few questions for my first day. Is there a dress code at [org name]? Also is there anything particular I need to prepare for work? Thank you.

Sincerely, 
[redacted]`

Comment: @MaxHodges I see you've used `code snippets` in a few comments. Please don't do that unless you're actually including code or something code-like in your comments, or posts, as it's often harder to read monospaced text and it messes things up for screen readers. I encourage you to use some other formatting instead, if you want to highlight or emphasize a part of what you post.